# Automatic cleanup of import * statements in python

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working in a python-2 code base with a lot of statements of the form

```
from Util import *
```

This is not good practice, so I'd like to replace them all with

```
import Util
```

and then add a `Util.` prefix all to variables/functions wherever necessary.

Hunting down all the spots where a prefix needs to be added would be a painstaking process. I am wondering if there is a good way of doing this in an automated fashion.

Comment: If you want, you could do `import Util as u` and then you just need to add `u.`

Comment: Do it by hand. That should teach you to never do `import *` again :-).

Comment: @Jim Over 100k lines of code, dozens of different modules from which `import *` is done...it seems possible to write an automated tool to do this in theory, no?

Comment: I was just joking around a bit :-). Don't some IDEs support this sort of substitution? When I used them I remember they did.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the python IDE landscape. Hopefully someone drops by with some knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to nicely identify the references.  If you *know* there are no name collisions (i.e. **Util** symbols with the same name as some other symbol), then you can grab the module's directory and loop through the symbols.  Go through the program and prepend **Util.**, as you said.

It sounds like you already know how to handle the string augmentation.  You get the symbol directory for a module like this:

```
import random
for random_name in dir(random):
    ...
```

To give you an idea, here's the list of random_name values:

```
BPF
LOG4
NV_MAGICCONST
RECIP_BPF
Random
SG_MAGICCONST
SystemRandom
TWOPI
WichmannHill
_BuiltinMethodType
_MethodType
__all__
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
_acos
_ceil
_cos
_e
_exp
_hashlib
_hexlify
_inst
_log
_pi
_random
_sin
_sqrt
_test
_test_generator
_urandom
_warn
betavariate
choice
division
expovariate
gammavariate
gauss
getrandbits
getstate
jumpahead
lognormvariate
normalvariate
paretovariate
randint
random
randrange
sample
seed
setstate
shuffle
triangular
uniform
vonmisesvariate
weibullvariate
```

Comment: In fact, there are name collisions, which is part of the motivation for the cleanup. For example some local variables have names that collide with variables from modules.

Comment: In that case, you'll need additional logic to recognize symbols in each new scope.  The solution for that is quite beyond the range of this site.  You're getting into the first levels of parsing ... although you could perhaps pre-process by having each scope dump its symbol directory in a format your editing program can use.

Comment: Yikes, I've never been told that any question of mine is quite beyond the range of this site. Jim hinted in a comment that some IDE's might be able to do this for me, which would be best.

Comment: It's not the question -- if the answer needed includes basic parsing techniques, *then* we're outside the bounds of SO.  A package would be great -- but asking for an off-site package is also beyond the bounds.  However, that's just one possible solution, so I don't anticipate anyone trying to close this question.